# Displaying a File without Adjacent Duplicates in Python

Tags: python, duplicates

I'm trying to write a file that displays a text file So I want the program to display the file while it removes any adjacent identical lines. My question is that the code isn't working since I know I'm missing something and I was wondering how write the lines for this problem I'm facing?

```
input

1 
1 
2 
2 
1 
3 
1 
1 
1


then the output should be:
1 
2 
1 
3 
1
```

The code I have written right now is:

```
lines = open('list.txt', 'r').readlines()

lines_set = set(lines)

out  = open('list.txt', 'w')

for line in lines_set:
    out.write(line)

print(set(f.readlines()))
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: You would have to test this line and the previous line and only print if they are different.  Note that  "lines_set = set(lines)" does not keep the original order, and removes duplicates.  Add some print statements so you know what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment to the question, `set()` is not what you want because it will remove *all* duplicates, not just *adjacent* duplicates. You need something more like this:

```python
with open(r'C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\list_in.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    lines = f_in.readlines()

with open(r'C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\list_out.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    prev_line = ''
    for line in lines:
        if line != prev_line:
            f_out.write(line)
            prev_line = line

with open(r'C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\list_out.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print(line),
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you! It didn't click that I was removing ALL duplicates, not just adjacent duplicates. This makes sense, @gord you genius!